# error al compilar binding to reference of type discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, map, iteradores, constantes

al ejecutar un programa en el que entre otras funciones, minimizo un autómata finito determinista (DFA, para más información, https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aut%C3%B3mata_finito_determinista), uso los contenedores set y map de la stl de C++, pero me da errores que no entiendo en esa función (dfaminimo), los errores son los siguientes:

Aprecio vuestra ayuda.

```
estadoDFA.cpp:34:12: error: binding ‘const std::map<char, int>’ to reference of type ‘std::map<char, int>&’ discards qualifiers
     return trans_;
```

refiriéndose a la siguiente línea del fichero estadoDFA:

```
map<char,int>&  estado:: get_transiciones(void) const{
        return trans_; //LINEA 34
    }
```

en esa funcion he hecho infinidad de parches, poniendo que lo que devuelve siempre es `const`, poniendo que el `const` va despues de `get_transiciones(void)`, pero me da un montón de errores más.

el segundo error:

map&  estado:: get_transiciones(void) const{
        return trans_;
    }

PD: he mirado preguntas similares con el mismo error, probando las soluciones que se proponen, pero no me compila.

DFA.cpp:414:74: error:    ‘class std::map’ has no member named ‘second’
                                if(partvieja[k].find((*it).get_transiciones().second) == partvieja[k].end()){

Este error tampoco lo entiendo.

Aquí dejo el código de las funciones con error:

el de dfaminimo en DFA.cpp

```
void dfa::dfaminimo(){
            //cjtos.push_back(cjto);
                        //un vector al que le inserto cosas parametro
            map<char,int>::iterator it1;

            //vector<set<int> > cjtos;
            set<estado> particion1; //el estado de muerte
            set<estado> particion2; //el resto de estados
            vector<set<estado> >  conjuntos;

            //no hace falta llamar a la funcion operator <, lo llama insertar en su implementacion interna
            //particion2=cjtos;
            for(int i=0;i<estados_.size();i++){
                if(estados_[i].get_aceptacion()!=true){
                    particion2.insert(estados_[i]); 

                }
                else{
                    particion1.insert(estados_[i]);

                }
             }

            conjuntos.push_back(particion1);
            conjuntos.push_back(particion2);
            vector<set<estado> > temporal;
            do{

                temporal = conjuntos;
                conjuntos = crear_nueva_particion(temporal);
            }while(conjuntos.size()!=temporal.size());


            construir_dfa(conjuntos);



        }
```

Aquí las funciones que son llamadas:

```
vector<set<estado> > dfa::crear_nueva_particion(vector<set<estado> > temporal){
           vector<set<estado> > conjunto;

           for(int i=0; i<temporal.size();i++){
               //conjunto = conjunto | descomp(temporal[i],temporal);
               set<estado> newpart = descomp(temporal[i],temporal);
               //set<estado>::iterator it1;

               conjunto.push_back(newpart);
           }


           //unione.push_back(operando2);

           return conjunto;

           //return unione;
        }
```

Aquí la función descomponer, donde separo los conjuntos

```
set<estado> dfa::descomp(set<estado> conj, vector<set<estado> > partvieja){


           set<estado> T = conj;
           map<char, int>::iterator it1;
           set<char> simbolos;//simbolos del alfabeto que el DFA reconoce
           for(it1=estados_[0].get_transiciones().begin();it1!=estados_[0].get_transiciones().end();it1++){
               simbolos.insert((*it1).first);
           }

           set<char>::iterator it2;
           for(it2=simbolos.begin(); it2!=simbolos.end();it2++){

               set<estado> P;
               set<estado>::iterator iterador;

               for(iterador= T.begin(); iterador!=T.end();iterador++){
                   set<estado> Tprima = part(conj,(*it2),partvieja);

                   //P = P | Tprima;
                   set<estado>::iterator it1;
                   for(it1= Tprima.begin(); it1!=Tprima.end();it1++){
                        P.insert((*it1));
                   }
               }

               T = P;
           }
           return T;

       }
```

Gracias

Comment: Tu problema no tiene nada que ver con autómatas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error te está indicando claramente cuál es el problema, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, permítieme traducirlo:

> error: binding `const std::map<char, int>` to reference of type `std::map<char, int>&` discards qualifiers

> error: vincular `const std::map<char, int>` a una referencia de tipo `std::map<char, int>&` descarta cualificadores

---

Básicamente te está diciendo que un objeto de tipo constante no puede ser referenciado por una referencia no constante. En C++ es ilegal tener una referencia no constante a un objeto constante.

El objeto `trans_` que devuelves en la función `get_transiciones` es constante porque la función es constante:

```
//           /--- referencia
//           v           funcion constante ---> vvvvv
map<char,int>&  estado:: get_transiciones(void) const{
    return trans_;
//         ^^^^^^ <--- es constante porque get_transiciones es constante
}
```

#### Solución.

Puedes solucionar este problema de dos maneras: haciendo el retorno constante o quitando el cualificador de la función:

```
//  /--------------+--- referencia constante
//  v              v           funcion constante ---> vvvvv
const map<char,int>&  estado:: get_transiciones(void) const{
    return trans_;
//         ^^^^^^ <--- es constante porque get_transiciones es constante
}
```

O sin constante:

```
//           v <--- referencia
map<char,int>&  estado:: get_transiciones(void){
    return trans_;
//         ^^^^^^ <--- NO ES CONSTANTE
}
```

Comment: Hola @PaperBirdMaster, publicaré otra duda porque al hacer los cambios me han salido errores que me salían antes y que corregí poniendo const, como comentario no cabe toda la pregunta.