# error passing as this argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, map, iteradores

me salen una serie de errores al compilar un código que calcula varias funciones de un autómata finito y que llevo un rato intentando resolver:

primer error:

```
 passing ‘const estado’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 if((*it).get_transiciones().find(simbolo) != (*it).get_transiciones().end()){
```

otro error:

```
 error: passing ‘const estado’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   if((*it).get_transiciones().find(simbolo) != (*it).get_transiciones().end()){



note:   in call to ‘std::map<char, int>& estado::get_transiciones()’
         map<char,int>&  estado:: get_transiciones(void){
```

Otro error:

```
passing ‘const estado’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
                            if(partvieja[k].find((*it).get_transiciones().second) == partvieja[k].end()){



‘class std::map<char, int>’ has no member named ‘second’
                            if(partvieja[k].find((*it).get_transiciones().second) == partvieja[k].end()){
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda, gracias.
Esta es la función que da los errores:

el de dfaminimo en DFA.cpp

```
void dfa::dfaminimo(){
            //cjtos.push_back(cjto);
                        //un vector al que le inserto cosas parametro
            map<char,int>::iterator it1;

            //vector<set<int> > cjtos;
            set<estado> particion1; //el estado de muerte
            set<estado> particion2; //el resto de estados
            vector<set<estado> >  conjuntos;

            //no hace falta llamar a la funcion operator <, lo llama insertar en su implementacion interna
            //particion2=cjtos;
            for(int i=0;i<estados_.size();i++){
                if(estados_[i].get_aceptacion()!=true){
                    particion2.insert(estados_[i]); 

                }
                else{
                    particion1.insert(estados_[i]);

                }
             }

            conjuntos.push_back(particion1);
            conjuntos.push_back(particion2);
            vector<set<estado> > temporal;
            do{

                temporal = conjuntos;
                conjuntos = crear_nueva_particion(temporal);
            }while(conjuntos.size()!=temporal.size());


            construir_dfa(conjuntos);



        }
```

Aquí las funciones que son llamadas:

```
vector<set<estado> > dfa::crear_nueva_particion(vector<set<estado> > temporal){
           vector<set<estado> > conjunto;

           for(int i=0; i<temporal.size();i++){
               //conjunto = conjunto | descomp(temporal[i],temporal);
               set<estado> newpart = descomp(temporal[i],temporal);
               //set<estado>::iterator it1;

               conjunto.push_back(newpart);
           }


           //unione.push_back(operando2);

           return conjunto;

           //return unione;
        }
```

Aquí la función descomponer, donde separo los conjuntos

```
set<estado> dfa::descomp(set<estado> conj, vector<set<estado> > partvieja){


           set<estado> T = conj;
           map<char, int>::iterator it1;
           set<char> simbolos;//simbolos del alfabeto que el DFA reconoce
           for(it1=estados_[0].get_transiciones().begin();it1!=estados_[0].get_transiciones().end();it1++){
               simbolos.insert((*it1).first);
           }

           set<char>::iterator it2;
           for(it2=simbolos.begin(); it2!=simbolos.end();it2++){

               set<estado> P;
               set<estado>::iterator iterador;

               for(iterador= T.begin(); iterador!=T.end();iterador++){
                   set<estado> Tprima = part(conj,(*it2),partvieja);

                   //P = P | Tprima;
                   set<estado>::iterator it1;
                   for(it1= Tprima.begin(); it1!=Tprima.end();it1++){
                        P.insert((*it1));
                   }
               }

               T = P;
           }
           return T;

       }
```

Edito, aquí está el main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"DFA.cpp"
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

/** en el main se hace el menu con las opciones*/
int main (void){
int opcion;

  string nombre;
  string nombre2;

  dfa objeto1;
  //dfa objeto2;
  //dfa objeto3;
  //vector<objeto2> particion1;
  //vector<objeto3> particion2;
  char c;
  int i=0;
  bool leido=false;

  do{

    cout<<"1.Leer DFA "<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Mostrar DFA"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Estados de muerte "<<endl;
    cout<<"4.Minimizar DFA "<<endl;
    cout<<"5.Exportar DFA "<<endl;
    cout<<"6.Analizar cadena "<<endl;
    cout<<"7.Salir del programa"<<endl;
    cin>>opcion;
    if(opcion==1){
        leido=true; 
    }

    if(opcion==4 || opcion==5 || opcion== 6){
        if(leido==true)
            cout<<"Correcto"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"Antes de elegir esta opcion, primero tiene que cargar un dfa con la opcion Leer DFA "<<endl;
    }
    switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            {
            cout<<" Introduzca el nombre del fichero "<<endl;
                cin.clear();

            getchar();

            getline(cin,nombre);

                ifstream F(nombre.c_str());
            cout<<"entra"<<endl;


                F>>objeto1;

            cout<<"listo"<<endl;
            break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                objeto1.mostrar(cout);
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                objeto1.estados_muerte();
                break;
            }
        case 4:
            {
                objeto1.dfaminimo();
                break;
            }
        case 5:
            {

                cout<<"Cual es el nombre que le quiere dar al fichero"<<endl;
                cin>>nombre2;

                objeto1.exportarDFA(nombre2);
                break;
            }
        case 6:
            {
                objeto1.analizarcadena();
                break;
            }

        default:
                cout<< "Cerrando el programa "<<endl;


    }
    }while(opcion!=7);
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Es el mismo problema que [en tu anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113257/error-al-compilar-binding-to-reference-of-type-discards-qualifiers), tienes funciones `const` que están ejecutando código no constante. ¿Qué tienes en `main`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Ahora te paso el main

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que querías `inclu`ir un `cpp`?

Comment: No veo en ningún lado el código que te produce el error que describes. Pero sigue siendo el mismo problema que [en tu anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113257/error-al-compilar-binding-to-reference-of-type-discards-qualifiers): Tienes funciones `const` que están ejecutando código no constante.